# Ant Build: Not finding local.properties or build_web_extras.properties

Tags: apache, maven, ant, build

Just installed Apache Ant and Maven Ant tasks. I have a build.xml in my project that I'm trying to run as an Ant Build, but when I try to run it, it returns the following:

```
    Unknown argument: -build
Buildfile: C:\Users\arempel\workspace\cis\cisbackend\build.xml
[mvn:dependencies] [INFO] snapshot choicehotels.util.io:choice-io:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT: checking for updates from nexus
[mvn:dependencies] [WARNING] repository metadata for: 'snapshot choicehotels.util.io:choice-io:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT' could not be retrieved from repository: nexus due to an error: Error transferring file: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[mvn:dependencies] [INFO] Repository 'nexus' will be blacklisted
local-properties-found:
local-properties-not-found:
     [echo] local.properties file not found in ../.., ../, or C:\Users\arempel/eclipse_properties
build-web-extras-found:
build-web-extras-not-found:
     [echo] build_web_extras.properties file not found in ../.., ../, or C:\Users\arempel/eclipse_properties
report-local-properties:
-verify_local_properties:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\arempel\workspace\cis\cisbackend\build.xml:47: local.properties or build_wewb_extras.properties file not found

Total time: 1 second
```

I'm not sure where to start looking to fix this. It might be an environment variable but I have Ant added under Users\myusername\apache-ant-1.9.1, so I'm not sure what I need to do.

EDIT: Added the build.xml

```
<project name="cisbackend" default="local" basedir="."
       xmlns:mvn="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">


<!-- ===================== Property Definitions =========================== -->
  <!-- locate the local.properties and build_web_extras.properties files within the workspace -->
  <import file="../locate-local-properties.xml" />

  <property file="${local.properties.dir}/build_web_extras.properties"/>

  <property environment="env"/>
  <property name="app.name"            value="cisbackend"/>

  <property name="compile.debug"       value="true"/>
  <property name="compile.deprecation" value="false"/>
  <property name="compile.optimize"    value="false"/>

  <property name="compile.home"        value="target"/>
  <property name="package.home"        value="target/package"/>
  <property name="resources"           value="src/main/resources" />

  <property name="xsl.home"            value="${resources}/xsl"/>
  <property name="images.home"         value="${resources}/images"/>
  <property name="dist.home"           value="target/dist"/>

    <!-- -->
    <macrodef name="runmvn">
        <element name="args" optional="yes"/> 

        <sequential>
          <mvn:mvn mavenHome="${env.MAVEN_HOME}" fork="true" dir="${basedir}" failonerror="true">
             <args />  <!-- additional arg elements specified by the caller-->
          </mvn:mvn>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

  <!-- Set up the compiler CLASSPATH -->
  <mvn:dependencies filesetId="maven.dependencies" useScope="compile">
     <pom file="pom.xml"/>
  </mvn:dependencies>

   <path id="compile.classpath">
     <fileset refid="maven.dependencies" />
   </path>

    <target name="-verify_local_properties" depends="report-local-properties">
      <fail message="local.properties or build_wewb_extras.properties file not found" unless="configuration-is-valid" />
    </target>   


<!-- ==================== Clean Target ==================================== -->

  <target name="clean">
    <runmvn>
        <args>
             <arg value="clean"   />
        </args>
    </runmvn>
  </target>

<!-- ==================== Compile Target ================================== -->

  <target name="-compile">
        <runmvn>
            <args>
            <arg value="compile"   />
        </args>
      </runmvn>

  </target>

<!-- ==================== Build Target ==================================== -->

  <target name="-build" depends="-compile">

    <mkdir dir="${package.home}/lib"/>

    <!-- Copy jar files into the package directory -->
    <jar  destfile="${package.home}/lib/cisbackend.jar" 
           basedir="${compile.home}/classes">
        <exclude name="*"/>
    </jar>

    <copy    todir="${package.home}/lib" flatten="true">
      <fileset refid="maven.dependencies" />
    </copy>


    <!-- Copy property files and stylesheets -->
    <copy todir="${package.home}/classes">
      <fileset dir="target/classes" includes="*"/>
    </copy>

    <!-- Copy scripts -->
    <copy todir="${package.home}">
      <fileset dir="src/scripts"/>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${package.home}/control">
      <fileset dir="src/control"/>
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${package.home}/xsl">
       <fileset dir="${xsl.home}"/>
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${package.home}/images">
       <fileset dir="${images.home}"/>
    </copy>


  </target>

<!-- ==================== Replace Target ================================= -->

  <target name="-replace">

    <echo message="Replacing tokens found in property file ${replace.file}"/>

    <!-- Copy environment specific configuration files -->
    <copy todir="${package.home}/${replace.dir}">
      <fileset dir="src/config"/>
    </copy>

    <replace dir="${package.home}/${replace.dir}"
             replaceFilterFile="${replace.file}"
             summary="yes"/>

  </target>

<!-- ==================== Dist Target ===================================== -->

  <target name="-dist">

    <mkdir dir="${dist.home}"/>

    <!-- For some reason ANT doesn't figure out the TAR file needs to be
         changed so delete it first -->
    <delete file="${dist.home}/cisbackend.tar"/>

    <!-- Create application TAR file -->
    <tar tarfile="${dist.home}/cisbackend.tar">
      <tarfileset dir="${package.home}" mode="755">
        <include name="*.sh"/>
      </tarfileset>
      <tarfileset dir="${package.home}">
        <include name="**"/>
        <exclude name="*.sh"/>
      </tarfileset>
    </tar>

    <mvn:install file="${package.home}/lib/cisbackend.jar">
      <pom file="pom.xml"/>
    </mvn:install>


  </target>

<!-- ==================== Deploy Target =================================== -->

  <target name="-deploy" depends="-dist">

    <!-- Deploy the TAR file -->
    <exec executable="/cis/cisdev/bin/copyanddeploy">
      <arg value="${version}"/>
      <arg file="${dist.home}/cisbackend.tar"/>
    </exec>

  </target>

    <target name="hudson.copytodeploy">
        <property file="target/classes/version.properties" prefix="project"/>
        <copy todir="${build.deploy.dir}" verbose="true">
            <fileset dir="${dist.home}" includes="*.war,*.tar"/>
            <globmapper from="*" to="*.${project.version.major}-${project.version.minor}-${project.version.build}" />
        </copy>
    </target>

<!-- ==================== Local Targets =================================== -->

  <target name="-local_replace" depends="-build">
    <!-- define default for dev.replace.file in case developer 
         does not define in build_web_extras.properties -->
    <property name="cisbackend.replace.file" value="dev1.properties" />

     <!-- replace tokens specified in the developer's local.properties file -->
    <antcall target="-replace">
      <param name="replace.file" value="${local.properties.dir}/local.properties"/>
      <param name="replace.dir"    value="config"/>
    </antcall>

     <!-- replace any additional tokens using the file 
          specified by the cisbackend.replace.file property in the developer's
          build_web_extras.properties file -->
    <antcall target="-replace">
      <param name="replace.file" value="${cisbackend.replace.file}"/>
      <param name="replace.dir"    value="config"/>
    </antcall>
  </target>

  <target name="local_clean" depends="clean"/>

  <!-- This target should be used for creating a build on your local machine.  -->
  <target name="local" description="Build the project for your machine"
    depends="-verify_local_properties, local_clean, -local_replace, -dist" />

<!-- ==================== Distribution Targets ============================ -->

  <target name="-dist-replace" depends="-build">
    <antcall target="-replace">
      <param name="replace.file" value="dev1.properties"/>
      <param name="replace.dir"  value="config-dev1"/>
    </antcall>
    <antcall target="-replace">
      <param name="replace.file" value="dev2.properties"/>
      <param name="replace.dir"  value="config-dev2"/>
    </antcall>
    <antcall target="-replace">
      <param name="replace.file" value="dev3.properties"/>
      <param name="replace.dir"  value="config-dev3"/>
    </antcall>      
    <antcall target="-replace">
      <param name="replace.file" value="qa2.properties"/>
      <param name="replace.dir"  value="config-qa2"/>
    </antcall>
    <antcall target="-replace">
      <param name="replace.file" value="qa1.properties"/>
      <param name="replace.dir"  value="config-qa1"/>
    </antcall>
    <antcall target="-replace">
      <param name="replace.file" value="prod1.properties"/>
      <param name="replace.dir"  value="config-prod1"/>
    </antcall>
  </target>

  <target name="-dist_clean" depends="clean"/>

  <!-- This target should be used for creating a release build. -->
  <target name="build.release" description="Build a release"
        depends="-dist_clean, -dist-replace, -dist"/>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you include your build file?

Comment: Yes, should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

1) Initially at the beginning of the build output that you posted there was `Unknown argument: -build`. I suppose that changing the *build* target name fixed it. Otherwise you need to state clearly which commands you're running and in which context.

2) The build seems to depend on the environment and the *local.properties* file is missing. You can either make sure it's there or ensure that you're pointing at the right location.
This could also be related to some properties not being imported properly, but only you would know that for sure..

---

What happens when you rename the *-build* target to just *build*?

See the concept of hidden/private targets:

- http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/private-targets-td1350568.html
- http://www.jrenard.info/blog/creating-private-targets-with-ant.html
- http://extendit.us/private-ant-targets/

Comment: changing -build to build gives me the exact same output when I try to run it.